# Could you give me the proof of this ODE problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let x : [0,∞) → $R^3$ denote a solution of the ODE

x'(t) = c$\times$x(t), $x(0)$ = $x_0$.

Here c is a fixed unit vector, × is the standard cross product on $R^3$ . Show
that the trajectory of x lies on a circle in $R^3$ , and give an equation for the
circle.

Comment: I have no ideas on this problem and cannot find a answer or hint in Google too. Can you give me some hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $x$ is orthogonal to $c\times x$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\,(x\cdot x)=2\,x\cdot x'=2\,x\cdot(c\times x)=0\implies x\cdot x=\text{constant.}
$$